# python - html - how to modify code by converting text outside of a tag into a tag

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

**How to replace/convert/correct  a string representing tag into a tag?**

I have below example where I need to clean some parts of the code and need to convert strings like `&lt;/div&gt;` into the proper tags

```
html = """
    <html>
     <body>
      <div>
      &lt;/div&gt;  <----- how to convert the line into </div>
      <div class="first_class">
       <h1 id="Header_1">
        Header_1
       </h1>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>  
"""
```

I tried

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")

tag = soup.find(text="&lt;")
tag.replace_with("<")

print(soup.prettify())
```

but this logic doesn't work, the find function doesn't pick up the string. The fact that the text is outside of any tag makes it more difficult. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Did you try: `soup.find(text="<")`? The string was encoded in the original HTML, but BeautifulSoup should have decoded them when parsing and therefore used the decoded version for matching find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.replace`

```
In [3]: print(html.replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>'))

    <html>
     <body>
      <div>
      </div>
      <div class="first_class">
       <h1 id="Header_1">
        Header_1
       </h1>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

To place into `BeautifulSoup` from a file. Open the file first, replace the malformed text and then load the contents to `BeautifulSoup`. Something like this

```
with open('malformed.html') as f:
    malformed = f.read()

html = malformed.replace('&lt;', '<').replace('&gt;', '>')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html)
```

Comment: @ aydow that works on the self contained example, however when I load the html from a file into beautifulsoup first and then try to replace I get an error  'NoneType' object is not callable. Do you know how to work around that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a function to decode them, such as `unescape` on `html.parser`.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

unescape = HTMLParser().unescape 
html = """
    <html>
     <body>
      <div>
      &lt;/div&gt;  <----- how to convert the line into </div>
      <div class="first_class">
       <h1 id="Header_1">
        Header_1
       </h1>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>  
"""

print(unescape(html))
```

Output

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div>
  </div>  <----- how to convert the line into </div>
  <div class="first_class">
   <h1 id="Header_1">
    Header_1
   </h1>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ kcorlidy, the logic doesn't work in case the html part is first parsed into BeautifulSoup like html=(, BeautifulSoup(open('C:\\Folder\Test.html'), 'html.parser'))  error: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: i ran `html=(BeautifulSoup(open('C:\\Folder\Test.html'), 'html.parser'))` but i did not get such error. If you want to read as bytes, use `open('C:\\Folder\Test.html','rb')`. Btw you must close the file when you reading finished. Use `with open('Test.html',"rb") as fd: html = BeautifulSoup(fd.read(), 'html.parser')`

Answer (score 0):

Try using regular expressions instead.

Something like:

```
html = re.sub("&lt;", "<", html)
```

for less-than and

```
html = re.sub("&gt;", ">", html)
```

for greater-than.

Make sure you `import re` first.

Edit: for reference on how to use re.sub - https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub

Edit2: After some further research it seems like str.replace() is faster, so you may want to use that instead.

Comment: @ jwoff, doesn't work in case the html is loaded from the file into BeautifulSoup first, do some operations and then try to replace at the end. I tried to convert the Beautifulsoap object into the string like str(html)  and replace and convert back to beautifulsoup for nice output format, but there were some small unexpected changes to the structure of the code.